# PWA service worker Google Chrome update in February about cache must be first

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, progressive-web-apps

After the February update, I am trying to solve the "cache must be first" ("network first" is not accepted by the Chrome in the future), at least for the PWA front page. Now PWA service worker must cache the PWA front page in order to install the SW, also ran the tests to confirm this:
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/improved-pwa-offline-detection/

Displaying a custom offline page from cache does not solve anything now. Front page must be always from the cache, if taken from the network, Chrome can not verify SW.

So if your front page must be dynamically changed by the server this gets complicated, because once the front page is cached your server can not change it any longer at least not that effectively. I am stuck with this cached front page.

I have not found any good solution only these ideas:

1. I need to update the service worker constantly, example if user name changes the cached page still shows the old name or news feed, I need to update the SW cache constantly with SW. (network first is soon not allowed).
2. I can use Ajax requests to serve fresh content part of the page, but the old cache is still shown until JavaScript loads the fresh content with Ajax on the mandatory cached page. Maybe I can block the page until fresh stuff... this can not be the right solution?
3. Redirect or disable links to PWA front page and use another page address.

I feel like I am missing something big.

How do you do?

Comment: I just use dynamic service worker file